# Is this function, a sum of one term and a convergent series, analytic?

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analyticity

$$(\frac{1}{z} + \sum z^n)$$

for 0<|z|<1.

This is for complex variables.  So, the series, convergent for the above domain of definition, *always* represents an analytic function.

What about the 1/z term?  Of course, it's bounded away from 0, and the inequalities for the domain of definition are strict.  So does that make the 1/z term bounded...for sure? Silly question, I know.  Sorry.

Thanks,

Comment: It's certainly not bounded -- I can choose $z$ such that $|1/z|$ is arbitrarily large in your domain. However, this doesn't make it not analytic on its domain, either.

Comment: You have not specified the sum, but that looks rather like $\dfrac{1}{x-x^2}$

Comment: Hi @Henry, yes, your sum is the one that I am referring to.  And I'm pretty sure it's analytic away from zero - there are no singularities in the above domain of definition.  What do you think?

Comment: Yes, it is analytic since it is complex differentiable at every point where it is defined.  It doesn't matter that its poles lie on the boundary of that open set. (complex analytic, as in, holomorphic).

Comment: @qaphla, thanks for the heads up.  I always struggle with this thought, since basic real analysis.  Then the unboundedness of 1/z makes me think that analyticity of the sum of the one term + the series ...is not preserved, since this sum would not be represented by a convergent series.

Comment: @LebronJames Yes, it is analytic in that annulus...though the last line in your last comment is a mistery for me.

Comment: Ok, got it - thanks @muaddib.  Is my language correct?  My saying that 1/z is "bounded away from zero", even though qaphla pointed out that 1/z is certainly not bounded.  I have heard "bounded away from zero" from professors and higher level students.

Comment: Hi @Timbuc, ok, got it.  Ya, I think I am just confusing myself a bit much.  Thanks :-)

Comment: @LebronJames For a function $f$ to be "bounded away from zero" on a set $S$ simply means that there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that for all $x \in S$, $|f(x) - 0| > \varepsilon$.  $\varepsilon$ is the bound, and $f$ never gets closer to zero than $\varepsilon$ on $S$. (There may be other usage, but this is the only one I've ever heard.)

Comment: @qaphla I have never heard that definition. From OP's comments, it seems like "bounded away from zero" means that the function is bounded on $\Bbb D\setminus N_0$ for any neighborhood $N_0$ of $0$ where $\Bbb D$ is the unit disk.

Comment: It is a *meromorphic$*  function, i.e. a holomorphic function on $\mathbf C$, except for a finite number of poles,  defined with a Laurent series.

Comment: @GPerez And I've never heard the definition that OP seems to be using. By that one, yes, $f$ is bounded away from zero. However, since terminology varies so much from place to place, it's good to be clear about what's meant by phrases like this.

Comment: @qaphla, I think I'm going to start a new question for this also.  That phrase has come up several times during the academic year, but during proofs in lecture, which just moves too fast for me to stop the prof. and ask such a seemingly simple thing to understand for many other students.  yet, this phrase doesn't get used in textbooks and textbook proofs - at least not what I have read during these last couple years of math training...